# Retorno de la moda en una cadena de caracteres

Tags: python

espero estén muy bien. Necesito ayuda con un ejercicio de programación en Python, el enunciado dice así:

-En este ejercicio deberás identificar la letra más común (o moda) en una cadena recibida por parámetro. Crea una función que reciba una cadena (str) que contenga la letra más común en la cadena inicial. Para tu facilidad, las cadenas que recibirás solo contendrán letras mayúsculas y no tendrán tildes ni acentos. No obstante, estas pueden tener espacios, puntos y comas. En caso de que haya 2 letras con la misma cantidad de apariciones, debes retornas la que sea alfabéticamente posterior.

Ya desarrollé un código que resuelve casi todos los test, sin embargo falla cuando hay que retornar la aparición alfabéticamente posterior, es decir, si la cadena recibida por parámetro es "AAAADDDDBB", debería retornas el str "D", pero solo logro retornar la "A". Otro ejemplo sería, "ABCDEFG", como todas se repiten 1 vez, se debe retorna la "G". Si alguien me ayuda a solucionarlo o lo resuelve de otra forma en código lo agradecería mucho. Les adjunto mi código.

'''

```
def letra_mas_comun(cadena: str)-> str:
    analisis = list(cadena)
    histograma = {}

    for i in range(0, len(analisis)):
      almacen = analisis[i]

      if almacen in histograma:
        histograma[almacen] += 1
        if almacen == " " or almacen == "." or almacen == ",":
          histograma[almacen] -= 10
      else:
        histograma[almacen] = 1

      palabra_mayor = max(histograma, key = histograma.get)


      x = histograma[palabra_mayor]
      
      if x == 1:
        palabra_mayor = analisis[-1]      

    return palabra_mayor
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema que tiene tu código es que estas obteniendo únicamente el valor máximo con la función `max()` pero en ningún momento comparas si hay algún otro miembro de tu diccionario `histograma` con la misma cantidad

En lugar de hacer:

```
palabra_mayor = max(histograma, key = histograma.get)
```

Podrías utilizar un ciclo `for` e iterar para analizar el histograma:

```
mayor = 0
  for letter, count in histograma.items():
    if (count >= mayor):
      mayor = count
      palabra_mayor = letter
```

El código completo sería (Eliminé la parte de `x` porque supuse que estabas intentando hacer algo en caso de que el valor fuera 1 en todas las letras)

```
def letra_mas_comun(cadena: str)-> str:
  analisis = list(cadena)
  histograma = {}
  

  for i in range(0, len(analisis)):
    almacen = analisis[i]

    if almacen in histograma:
      histograma[almacen] += 1
      if almacen == " " or almacen == "." or almacen == ",":
        histograma[almacen] -= 10
    else:
      histograma[almacen] = 1
      
  mayor = 0
  for letter, count in histograma.items():
    if (count >= mayor):
      mayor = count
      palabra_mayor = letter

  return palabra_mayor
```

Comment: Te agradezco muchísimo por la respuesta. Justamente estaba pensando en crear algún tipo de lista para almacenar las llaves con mayor valor. Con dicha solución aprendo mucho más. Que tengas feliz día.

Comment: @JuanPabloAguilar, si te sirvió la respuesta no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas